# How to charge a body and flow of charges

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electricity, charge

If a positively charged plastic is placed on top of a neutral metal plate, what is this type of charging called and what will be the flow of charges?

Comment: Well I wrote that its charging by induction and flow of electrons from metal to plastic.... A friend of mine wrote charging by contact and both will have shared charge. Which one is correct? Can you explain ?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that When you say charging by placing a plastic bag over a neutral metal surface, you are trying to say that there is no contact between the two bodies. 
That would mean that the plate as whole will still be neutral(if it is not grounded) but there will be a induced charge distribution on the surface of the conductor. For this to be a correct example of charging by induction, you have to earth that neutral metal plate and then the answer is charging by induction.
But if you meant that the two bodies will come in contact, then it is charging by contact and the two bodies will share some charge.The charge transfer will stop when they have the same electric Potential.

Answer (score 0):

I shall assume that the metal plate is on an insulating support. Its also convenient to suppose that, at first, there is a small air gap between the metal and the plastic.

Some of the 'free' electrons in the metal plate will be attracted to its top surface by the presence of the positively charged plastic. So the top surface of the metal plate will acquire a negative charge, and the bottom surface (somewhat depleted of electrons) a positive charge. The plate as a whole stays neutral.

Suppose that the plastic is now allowed to rest on the metal. At places where the plate touches the plastic, some of the excess electrons on the top surface of the plate may 'hop on to' the plastic, neutralising its charge *locally*, and giving the metal a net positive charge. This is unlikely to happen right across the bottom surface of the plastic, even where it appears to be in contact with the metal; on a microscopic scale the plastic will really only be in contact with the metal in a few places. So it would be misleading to think of the plastic 'sharing' its charge with the metal to any appreciable extent. Remember that although the plastic has been given a surface charge (no doubt by rubbing it with a different insulating material), charge can't then move about in or on the plastic; it's an insulator!

There is another scenario, however. Suppose that you touch the plate when the charged plastic is near it. Electrons, attracted by the plastic, will flow on to the plate from the ground through you! The plate will acquire a *negative* charge. This is what is called "charging (a conductor) by induction". It's a much more reliable way of giving a conductor a charge than having a charged insulator in contact with the conductor – but don't forget that in charging by induction the conductor acquires an opposite charge from the nearby charged object.

Comment: Well answered philip and sidharth. Thanks for the quick reply. The question was that they are both initially placed on top of each other ( plastic above metal) I think they were put on an insulating stand. Third question under this topic was : will the flow of charges ( you mentioned from previous question if any ) will keep the two objects together or no ?

Comment: It depends what you mean by 'flowed'. In the state described in my second paragraph (equal and opposite charges on either face of the metal plate, the plate will be attracted to the plastic (because the negative face is nearer the plastic, whose electric field will be non-uniform). What are your thoughts on what will happen to the strength of the force in (a) the scenario described in my third para, (b) the scenario described in my last para?

Comment: Your last paragraph sounds right and convincing even the one before however you said that plastic - being an insulator - will acquire some charge but these cannot move, having said that I am now confused a bit because charging bu rubbing lets say a plastic rod with a cloth involves flow of electrons- negative charges. So how would you explain this? Nevertheless, I don't currently know or have a correct answer for my question so I can't judge on any opinion I find here..

Comment: I meant that charge can't flow through the plastic, even from one bit of the plastic to another. But electrons can hop on and off the surface of the plastic from or to something that is contact with it. That's what happens when you rub the plastic with a cloth.  But when you merely rest the plastic on the metal plate, I wouldn't expect much charge transfer to take place, because of the imperfect contact.

Comment: I got it now that's sounds right perhaps, as I have got to know that even paper which feels smooth has actually many bumps and pits. Thanks.

Comment: About the strength of the forces : I think that in a) the force will remain strong unless one of them loses its charge or the distance betweeen them is increased. b) is it possible to say that it(strength of force/attraction) will increase since metal is receiving more electrons from ground through the person ?and positive  ions in metal might escape in opposite way ? Or are the ppsitive ions held in position and there is no way that they can get out/move and if they did escape will it  result in breakage of lattice holding them ? Have I gone too far

Comment: Well done for attempting these answers. In (a) you'd expect the attractive force to weaken, or even become repulsive, because the plate now has a net positive charge, as it is gave away some of its electrons to the plastic. In (b) (last para of answer) the attractive force will be considerably strengthened, because the plate now has a negative charge (rather than separated positive and negative charges on its bottom and top surfaces), and the plastic a positive charge.

Comment: Glad I got second one right... thanks for your help.

Comment: Hope you've also read VF's answer. I ignored the role of ions in the air as conveyors of charge, because I think the changes they bring about are relatively slow (there are not huge numbers of ions around), but eventually they do play a significant part – as VF explains.

Comment: Yes, I got that.

Answer (score 0):

If a positively charged plastic is placed on top of a neutral, ungrounded, metal plate, two things will happen: quick redistribution of electrons inside the metal and gradual migration of some of the positive charge from plastic to metal, mostly through the ionized air, but some, possibly, though a direct contact.

Even in the absence of a nearby metal object, the charged plastic will be discharging into the air by attracting existing or induced negative ions of air molecules. Meanwhile, positive ions will flow out and end up deposited on nearby objects or just hang around for a while.

The presence of a nearby metal object on one side of the charged plastic will strengthen the electric field in the direction of the plate (due to the redistribution of electrons in the plate), which will speed up the flow of positive ions in that direction. As a result, the metal will gradually acquire some positive change.

Of course, over time, all initial positive charge will be dissipated and both plastic and metal will become neutral.

So, I believe that a correct answer to the question is that the charging of the metal plate will happen through the flow of charges, but it would be the flow of ions of air molecules - not the flow of electrons. The redistribution of electrons in the ungrounded metal plate, induced by the charged plastic, would not change the neutrality of the metal and, therefore, the induction should not be listed as one of the charging mechanisms. It is possible that some electrons will move from metal to plastic on direct contact, but the contribution of that mechanism is probably insignificant.